# Formatting 3 buttons in bootstrap (responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm just wondering what's the best way to format three buttons so that they show correctly on various screen sizes. So, this is what I've done so far and it looks good on 1200px width screen.

What I've done is I used the buttons and put them into span4 classes. Like so:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">
    <a class="header-btn" href="#">Testbutton 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <a class="header-btn" href="#">
      Testbutton 2
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <a class="header-btn" href="#">Testbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I shrink the screen size it looks bad and the buttons break up.

I would like to have the buttons displayed below one another once the screen size gets too small.

I could edit the span4 class from bootstrap but this could mess with the other layout... So should I just add a new class and make everything reponsive, or work with the bootstrap framework?

Please advise. 
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think you're using Bootstrap correctly, span4 isn't a class that Bootstrap uses, if you want 3 buttons in a line, that should be col-sm-4

Comment: It's 2.3.0 I believe.

Comment: @Lee Technically the code is correct since he's using version 2: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: Consider upgrading to v3 or v4 alpha.

Comment: That currently is not an option. Any hint on how I can solve that with v.2?

Comment: @Maddrax Why isn't it an option? Are you developing the website?

Comment: kinda afraid changing all the classes of the theme right now and mess everything up.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using it right for v2, so maybe you might not be having bootstrap loading in correctly.

but I suggest upgrading to v3 or v4, you can learn more in the Docs. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

All buttons will be inline horizontally with each other but as the screen gets smaller. the buttons will adjust and then go vertically with each other. depending on how you have it set up. But this makes it responsive.

You might want something like this, in the html:

! **To see everything working the way it should, when you click the run snippet button. Click full page and then drag the side of the browser smaller and smaller, and you will see the buttons adjust.** !

I hope this helps!

```css
.div-container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }

button{
  margin-left: 45% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='div-container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>CLICK</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>CLICK</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
       <button class='btn btn-primary'>CLICK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```